# expression of $_1F_1$ at half integer first argument

Tags: special-functions, hypergeometric-function

I am looking to re-express ${}_1F_1(n+\frac12,b,x)$ for $n$ a positive integer. Actually, so is b. I wrote:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
{}_1F_1(n + \frac12,b,x) & = 1 + \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(2n+1)(2n+3)\ldots(2n+k-1)}{2^k b(b+1)\ldots(b+k-1)} \frac{z^k}{k!} \\
& =   1 + \sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{2n(2n+1)(2n+2)\ldots(2n+2k-1)}{  n(n+1)(n+2)\ldots (n+k-1)b(b+1)\ldots(b+k-1)} \frac{\left(\frac z2\right)^k}{k!}\\
& =\ldots 
\end{split}
 \end{equation}

So, the bottom part can be reexpressed as $bn$ of the ${}_1F_1$ function. What can I do to the top part? I was thinking of $_{2}F_1$ but I am not sure what to do with the numerator (and not even sure it can be so expressed). So, I have been stuck for a while!

Is there some expression (and simpler form) for this? Many thanks for suggestions!